# Why is Degrees-symbol ° not printing on Mac OS machine, but does print OK on Windows 10

Tags: c++, char, character-set

I have a short C++ program to calculate the wind-chill index given a temperature and wind speed.  It's working fine on a Windows 10 machine and outputing exactly as it should. To print the  degrees symbol ° I'm using `static_cast<unsigned char>(248)`.
However, I'm getting different results on a MAC. I assume this is because of the different character set encoding between each of the two machines. How can I get around this problem, to ensure the degrees-symbol ° will print on both?

Here is the line of code and screen print of the output

```
cout << "When temperature is " << temp << " degrees and wind speed is " << windSpeed 
     << " m/s, then the wind chill is " << tempEff << static_cast<unsigned char>(248) <<"C\n\n";
```

Output on Windows:
[image]
[image: Output on Windows]

However, the same code returns a "\370" on a Macbook/MAC OS, which is incorrect. See output here:

[image]
[image: Output on Mac OS]

Comment: Weird thing for me is that `static_cast<unsigned char>(248)>` prints the appropriate thing on my Windows machine but just trying to print `'°'` doesn't.

Comment: `\370` is 248 in base 8, octal. Degree is in Unicode U+00B0, **`\u00b0`**, decimal 176. The encoding of the command line on Windows can be different from the Windows encoding in the editor. It is a mess.

Comment: 248 is not the correct code for the degrees character. [This](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) is required reading.